# French Google Fonts not consistent on different devices with same browser

Tags: html, css, fonts, less, google-fonts

so I am doing a website for a french client I am currently working for and for website I am using font from Google Fonts called `Comfortaa` ..
The website is in French and thus using letters with accents such as `é` `à` and `è`

However, while these letters display correctly on my device, on Chrome, Safari, etc. like this `->`
[image: Displays correctly on Chrome and Safari on Mac]

On my client's device it displays letter with accents incorrectly on Safari like this.. `->`
[image: Displays incorrectly on Safari]

Do you have any idea what is the reason for this and how I can fix it?

I am importing font like this:

**HTML**

```
    <!--     Fonts      -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa"/>

LESS File

@font: 'Comfortaa', cursive;

body,html {
  font-family: @font;
  font-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: try to add accent with including languages to your fonts .
for example `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa&amp;subset=greek,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: Yes probably you have to add `subset=latin-ext` For complete extended support to Latin alphabet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to thanks for answer and let everyone know solution..
Even though solution to add
`subset=greek, latin-ext` such as

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa&amp;‌​subset=greek,latin-e‌​xt" rel="stylesheet">
```

was helpful, it didn't solve problem

..actual problem was that when copying french text (thus letters with accents) to IntelliJIDEA splits the accented letter into two characters -> for example the letter `e` and accent as separate character... thus it is needed to rewrite these letter in editor with one character accented letter...
this might be an issue with other IDE's so it's good to be aware of that :)